# How can I remove the default mm/dd/yyyy from TextField in matirial-ui?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using `material-ui` and I want to make a `datetime-picker`. If the user doesn't pick anything, I want to be visible only the label "Date", but as you can see in the pictures below, there are some default `mm/dd/yyyy`characters. Is there any way I can remove them?

You can hardly see the label because of those characters:
[image: you can hardly see the label because of those characters],

After I click, the label is up(what I want), but again, I have mm/dd/yyyy
[image: after i click, the label is up(what i want), but again, i have mm/dd/yyyy]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<Grid item>
       <TextField
        classes={{ root: classes.textFieldRoot }}
         name="Date"
         label="Date"
         type="datetime-local"
         />
    </Grid>
```

And this is what I want to get:

Before user clicks:
[image: before user clicks]

After user chooses date and time:
[image: after user chooses date and time]

Comment: Have you tried add `InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}` to the component?

Comment: Just add `focused` to your `TextField`, like this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-merkle-3qu2t?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Those characters are the localized prompt for the [HTML input tag with type='datetime-local'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local), not `some default mm/dd/yyyy characters`. Why do you want to remove them? Do you assume they may cause a problem? (They won't). Do you want to display your own prompt? How will the end user know *which* format is expected?

Comment: @foxxycodes what if there are multiple pickers? `focused` will only set the focus to one control at a time.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that is true, didn't think so far. Seems like Majid Mohammadi's answer works.

Comment: This is still not what i want! I have edited my post so you can see the results that I want

Comment: @Sandi Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i want!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it by `state`. When input is on focus or it has value, its type will change to `datetime-local` input. Otherwise when the input is on blur or has not value its type will change to `text` for achieving your aim.

```
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [focus, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const [hasValue, setHasValue] = useState(false);
  const onFocus = () => setFocused(true);
  const onBlur = () => setFocused(false);
  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        onFocus={onFocus}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        InputProps={{
          classes: {
            input: "CustomTextField"
          }
        }}
        onChange={(e) => {
          if (e.target.value) setHasValue(true);
          else setHasValue(false);
        }}
        label="Date"
        type={hasValue || focus ? "datetime-local" : "text"}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit sleepy-violet-tv1t4]

Answer (score 0):

Set a default `date` to the date component, `date` should be in the form `yyyy-mm-dd`.

```
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useState } from "react";

function getCurrentDate() {
    let date = new Date();
    let dd = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
    let mm = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");
    let yyyy = String(date.getFullYear());
    return yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
    // return a date in the form yyyy-mm-dd
  }
  

export default function App() {
  const [date,setDate] = useState(getCurrentDate());
  
  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        value={date}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setDate(e.target.value);
        }}
        label="Date"
        type={"date"}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```